# Webpack 4 closure issues with a shared bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I'm attempting to upgrade to Webpack 4 from 3 and having problems with a shared bundle's closure.

My webpack is set up to create a `shared.js` file sharing my code between `a.js` and `b.js`. In particular, in the `shared.js` bundle, there is an index file with a `store` variable. We export just a function called `getStore()`, which returns the `store`. This call for `getStore` happens in varying places in our `a.js` and `b.js` files.

The lineup of our scripts on our page looks like the below:

```
/** some html **/
<script src=""/scripts/shared.js""></script>
<script src=""/scripts/a.js""></script>
<script src=""/scripts/b.js""></script>
```

In Webpack 3, when calling the `getStore()` code that is in `shared.js` (the call coming) from `a.js` for the first time it creates an instance of `store` which then call returns `store` from the `getStore()` call. Any subsequent calls to `getStore()` from `a.js`, it no longer create an instance of `store` rather it returns the same values from the `getStore()`. Then after `a.js` completes and `b.js` runs, when `b.js` calls `getStore()`, it does not instantiate `store` rather it uses the same instance that `a.js` used. In this case `store` is the same instance across bother `a.js` and `b.js`.

However in Webpack 4, the behavior differs. When `a.js` calls code in `shared.js`, when the code first references `getStore()`, similar to before, it will create an new instance of `store`, and while `a.js` runs and calls `getStore()` it returns the same instance. However, when `b.js` makes an initial reference to `shared.js` code, it does not use the same instance `a.js` used, rather it creates a new instance of `store` and throughout the `b.js`'s script run, it references that second `store` when calling `getStore()`. In this case, there are two instances of `store`, each unique for `a.js` and `b.js`.

Not sure what's different in Webpack 4 that's causing this issue. We switched from using the `CommonChunksPlugin` in Webpack 3 and are now using the built-in Optimization setting. Below are how they were both configured.

WEBPACK 3:

```
plugins: [..., new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'shared',
    filename: '[name].js',
    minChunks: 2
})]
```

WEBPACK 4:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            shared: {
                name: 'shared',
                chunks: 'initial',
                minChunks: 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both Webpack configurations spit out roughly the same size files and when debugging and seeing the call stack, the calls for `getStore()` is coming in from the respective a/b.js files.

Is there an explanation as to why `a.js` and `b.js` get separate instances of the `shared.js` `store` object in Webpack 4 vs what getting the same instances as in Webpack 3? When scripts rely on one another, how are their closures/scopes supposed to handle shared code?

Answer (score 1):

Idk if you figured it out, but I'd like to share my findings.

**TL;DR:** Split chunk instantiates a new instance of the module in common chunks for each library that calls it.

Starting from the begging, your webpack library should have functions like the one below.

```js
var r = n(34);
```

This calls a method in that library that retrieves modules:

```js
function n(t) {
 if (n[t])
   return n[t].exports;
 var e = n[t] = {
   i: t,
   l: !1,
   exports: {}
 };
 return s[t].call(e.exports, e, e.exports, o),
 e.l = !0,
 e.exports
    }
```

I couldn't find any documentation this, but `t` is a number that used to reference  a module (Remember this).  `s` was an object that contained all the modules the library *could* use and `n` was an object that contained all of the modules *that have already been used* by the library, essentially caches them.  When `n[t]` doesn't exist, webpack adds a generic object into `n` and the calls `return s[t].call(e.exports, e, e.exports, o)` .

Let's say `t` was 34, webpack would call the following method

```js
    34: function(e, t, n) {
        "use strict";
        n.r(t);
        var r = n(36);
        t.default = function() {
            var e = r.a.pageLevelOOM && r.a.adinfoOOMHeader
              , t = r.a.pageLevelOOM && r.a.serverOOMHeader;
            return r.a.adinfoOverride ? e : t
        }
    },
```

**Quick side note**, common chunks is added to the window under `webpackJsonp`.  If you enter `window.webpackJsonp[0][1]` in your browser's console, you'll see an object that has numeric keys and values are functions.

Key part here is that webpack essentially instantiates each module in common chunks like this.  So each library would have it's own version of a module in common chunks.